# MOJO prediction gives exit status 127

Tags: r, h2o, mojo

I created a MOJO file with H2O and try to predict based on the saved modell with R. However, I get an exit status 127 error and could not find any solution.

I have updated to the latest H2O release. The issues only occurs with Windows, running the code on Kaggle gives no error at all.

```
>   modelpath <- h2o.download_mojo(fileh, path=getwd(), get_genmodel_jar=TRUE)
>   modelpath
```

[1] "DeepLearning_model_R_1560926535628_2.zip"

```
>   if(is.vector(X)) X <- t(X)
>   X <- as.matrix(X)
>   Ynew <-   h2o.mojo_predict_df(frame = X, mojo_zip_path=modelpath, verbose=T)
```

...

```
input_csv:      C:\Users\PAPERS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpem4zDz/input.csv 
mojo_zip:C:\Users\paperspace\Documents\DeepLearning_model_R_1560926535628_2.zip genmodel_jar:   C:/Users/paperspace/Documents/h2o-genmodel.jar 
output_csv:    C:\Users\PAPERS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpem4zDz/prediction.csv 
classpath:      C:/Users/paperspace/Documents/h2o-genmodel.jar 
java_options:   -Xmx4g -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m 
java cmd:       java -Xmx4g -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m -cp C:/Users/paperspace/Documents/h2o-genmodel.jar hex.genmodel.tools.PredictCsv --mojo C:\Users\paperspace\Documents\DeepLearning_model_R_1560926535628_2.zip --input C:\Users\PAPERS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpem4zDz/input.csv --output C:\Users\PAPERS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpem4zDz/prediction.csv --decimal 
Fehler in h2o.mojo_predict_csv(input_csv_path = input_csv_path, mojo_zip_path = mojo_zip_path,  : 
  SYSTEM COMMAND FAILED (exit status 127)
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In dir.create(tmp_dir) :
  'C:\Users\PAPERS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpem4zDz' existiert bereits
```

Comment: can you confirm that you are using h2o-3 3.24.0.5? the error seems to indicate that the path already exists but it don't look like you are doing anything wrong. can you also include details about your windows system for the purpose of reproducing what you are seeing. thanks!

Comment: r python version: 3.24.0.4. with Windows 7, 64 bit, 8gb (virtual machine from paperspace)